# Vector Rotation around a specific system question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, rotations

Can anyone help with this question?

Compute the vector $\vec{r} = 20_{x0}-10_{y0}+30_{z0}$ after it is rotated first around ${x0}$ by 30 degrees, and then around ${y0}$ by 60 degrees.

Attempt at a Solution which is wrong:

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\ 0 & \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\vartheta & 0 & -\sin\vartheta \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sin\vartheta & 0 & \cos \vartheta \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\ 0 & \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi \end{pmatrix} ^T 
 \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\ 0 & \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix} 20\\-10\\ 30\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 35.98\\-7.5\\ -7.009\end{pmatrix}$

$\varphi=30 deg, \vartheta =  60 deg$

$$ $$

Answer is \begin{pmatrix} 14.085\\-11.83\\ -6.83\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Your provided "answer" cannot be right because a rotation does not change the length of a vector. But your "answer" has a different length than the vector you started with.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. That was provided by our course instructor